# Get SQLite error using heroku db:push when I'm using PostgreSQL as development db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

I was having problems pushing data from my development db to Heroku.  I decided to switch to PostgreSQL as my development db and have updated database.yml and removed the sqlite gem from the gemfiles.

The app runs fine against PostgreSQL but when I try to run the command:

```
heroku db:push
```

I get an SQLite error which is puzzling because there is no reference to sqlite in my project:

```
 !    Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !    
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxxx
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: xx
  password: xx

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I'm using RVM and I have created a new gemset without any luck.

I even tried this but got the same SQLite error:

```
heroku db:push postgres://xx:xx@localhost/xx

 !    Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !    
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

I have also run bundle install and bundle update.

Johann

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same problem and solved it by moving taps into a development group in my gemfile- taps requires sqlite, which is what was causing the problem.

```
group :development do
  gem 'taps', :require => false # has an sqlite dependency, which heroku hates
end
```

Comment: tried that, but get the same error (I ran bundle install and update and commited to heroku before pushing db ... get an sqlite error).

Comment: Solved it - tekniklr answer put me on the correct track. The problem was that taps is using sqlite and that wasn't installed on the client machine (I think I manually removed it manually before). After I installed sqlite it worked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem. I thought it was a homebrew problem as I installed heroku manually in conjunction to using homebrew at some point to test something. 'gem install sqlite3' solved the problem.

Comment: taps doesn't have sqlite3 runtime dependency

Comment: It might not anymore, but 7 months ago it did :)

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to add not only `taps` gem but also `sqlite3` gem into the `:development` group. If you are using in your development `sqlite3` already, then just adding `taps` gem will be enough. But I am using `mysql` on my development so to solve that problem I had to add both.

```rb
group :development do
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gem install sqlite3
```

solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my debian wheezy I needed to install:

```
aptitude install libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install sqlite3
```

Is all you need.  The error is coming locally, not from Heroku